# Google calendar events are being recreated after deleting them. using ICS attachment

Tags: email, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am using ICS email attachments to create events and sync google calendar.

the events are created fine, But if I delete them and enter the gmail inbox, it is recreating the events.
the only workaround that works for me is to delete the emails with the attachments from inbox and trash.

Is that a known google calendar bug, or there is something I can change with my ICS file to solve this?
This is the ICS file I use:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:test-62fa4e2def6bf246cd4a3e52
METHOD:REQUEST
UID:cal-order-62fa4e2def6bf246cd4a3e52
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:test test
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Jerusalem;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20220816T100000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Jerusalem;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20220816T113000
UID:order-62fa4e2def6bf246cd4a3e52
SEQUENCE:0
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:MAILTO:test@gmail.com
DESCRIPTION:Number of persons: 2\nDuration: 1hr 30min\nPrice: 750 \n   
      \nFirst name: \nLast name: \nEmail: test@gmail.com\nPho
 ne: 0543098138
LOCATION:Test Harbor
NAME:Test Glass - 62fa4e2def6bf246cd4a3e52
ORGANIZER;CN=Test:MAILTO:test2@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: This is unhelpful, but googling suggests you've turned on a setting to do this and can turn it off somewhere. Most of the google results tell people how to turn this feature on, suggesting it's not on by default. I'm guessing the synching has to be unidirectional: it would be bad if deleting an event from the calendar deleted an attachment in your gmail

Comment: I find it hard to believe as it happens the same on multiple accounts. but just to make sure. can you send me a link? @BarryCarter

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/create-a-google-calendar-event-from-a-message-in-gmail-1172093 is one example. Quoting `In the app, access Settings > Events From Gmail, and move the slider to the On position.`